# Error passing between Model and ViewModel?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, repository

**In the previous question "ASP .NET Core Repository Id Article passed in was changed to 0?" I did it successfully, but due to a conflict with the team on GitHub, I had to rewrite my code. However, when I run it, I have a transmission error between Model and ViewModel. What is this and how do I fix it? I don't change anything between my code.**

---

**Controller**

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult EditArticle(Article article)
    {
        if(!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(article);
        }
        if(!_studentRepository.EditArticle(article))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("...");
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

---

**View**

```
    @model Megatron.ViewModels.ArticleFacultyViewModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Edit Article";
}
<div>
    <form asp-action="EditArticle">
        <partial name="_StatusMessage" model="@ViewData["Message"]" />
        <div>
            @Html.HiddenFor(a => a.Article.Id)
            <div class="form-group row">
                <div class="col-2">
                    <label asp-for="Article.Title" class="col-form-label"></label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-5">
                    <input asp-for="Article.Title" class="form-control" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row">
                <div class="col-2">
                    <label class="col-form-label">Type of contribution</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-3">
                    <button hidden class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#ImportFileCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="ImportFileCollapse">
                    </button>
                    <button hidden class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#TextAreaCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="TextAreaCollapse">
                    </button>
                    <button id="button-collapse" class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".multi-collapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="ImportFileCollapse TextAreaCollapse">
                        Switch to Editor
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You return a `Artical` type model to the View in the post method,

```
if(!ModelState.IsValid)
{
    return View(article);
}
```

While the view expect a
`ArticleFacultyViewModel` type model. You may convert it.

```
if(!ModelState.IsValid)
{
    var articleVM = new ArticleFacultyViewModel
    {
        Article = article,
        Faculties = _facultyRepository.GetFaculties()
    };
    return View(articleVM);
}
```

Comment: It is correct but it won't work. `article` will not be edited

Comment: **Like I said, my previous code worked. But when I rewrite it got a transmission error like this**

Comment: What's meaning of `article will not be edited` ? And what you rewrite?

Comment: It won't **edit the Article** in the database, it will return the edit page with the changes I made.

Comment: It means the model didn't pass the validation, the `ModelState.IsVaild` is false, so it return back to your edit view. So can you receive the article successfully, maybe you can show us your article model and viewmodel.

Comment: I added `Model` and `ViewModel`

Comment: The `Author` property is required, it can not be null, while you didn't set it in your view. Try to add it.

Comment: **If it matters, I wonder why is my previous code executing normally? I've included my previous question link at the top of this post ...**

Comment: I don't see there is `Author` property in your previous thread, did you add it later?

Comment: My team added this, I didn't know it soon. This has affected the code. **Thank you very much.**